# Sending an ArrayList<byte[]> over a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, arrays

Basically what I have is a Packet class which implements Serializable. Within this Packet class I have two ArrayList of type byte[]. I have no trouble sending over a Packet containing two ArrayList of type String.

The main reason I need to send it over as an ArrayList of type byte[] is because I first have to encrypt the data. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public class Packet implements Serializable
{

        private ArrayList<byte[]> data;             // String data to be sent
        private ArrayList<byte[]> data2;            // Numeric data to be sent
        private Encryption encryption;              // Encrypts data using RSA

        public void insertString(String input)
        {
            byte[] dataToBeSent = encryption.encrypt(input, encryption.getPublicKey());
            data.add(dataToBeSent);
        }
}
```

I am now wondering how I can send the byte arrays through a socket from within the Packet class?

Comment: "I have no trouble sending over a Packet containing two ArrayList." OK, so what's your question, then?

Comment: What's your question...?

Comment: For some reason it didn't put in my text properly. I have no problem sending it as an ArrayList<String>. The problem is sending as ArrayList<byte>

Comment: How do I send these byte arrays accross with the Packet class?

Comment: I edited the original question

Comment: The same way you sent the arrayList<String>.... serialize it with an ObjectOutputStream, or some custom serializer.

Comment: I see my mistake. It was in fact the Encryption object that was causing the serialization issues :)